# How to get xhost on Termux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, xterm, termux

I am trying to use tkinter on termux and for in I need xhost. When I run `xhost +` I get the output `xhost not found` how would I get xhost on termux so I can run tkinter?

Things that dont work:

`pkg install xhost`